# making a list of tuples from a string,,

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I'd like to make a list of tuples out of a string. Basically, given the following,

```
s = "a b c d"
w = s.split()
```

I'd like to have the list of tuples below:

```
[(a, b), (b, c), (c, d)]
```

I feel like I should use the append function and a for-loop, but I am stuck. How can I do it?

Comment: what language are you dealing with?

Comment: Python!!-- The codes below work fine!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> s = "a b c d"
>>> w = s.split()
>>> zip(w, w[1:])
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]
```

If you really want to use a `for` loop and `append`, you can replace the `zip()` like this

```
>>> res = []
>>> for i in range(1, len(w)):
...     res.append((w[i-1], w[i]))
... 
>>> res
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Comment: Thanks!! Both work fine, though the first code is simpler!!--

Answer (score 1):

```
     s = "a b c d"
     s = s.split(" ")
     c=[]
     for i in range(len(b)-1):
            c.append((b[i],b[i+1]))


    list comprehension
    s = "a b c d"
    s = s.split(" ")
    d=[(s[i],s[i+1])for i in range(len(s)-1)]
```